# Png image not showing in website used in react.js

Tags: reactjs, xml, image, tags, src

Png image is not showing in website while importing it in img src line of xml code inside react.js.

I used
<img src={require ("../../../Assets/Home/footer-image.png").default} alt='error loading image'/>
inside xml div in react.js and I was expecting that the image will show in my website. My location is also correct but I'm not getting the result and in website it's showing error loading image.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .default at the end of the require:

```
<img src={require ("../../../Assets/Home/footer-image.png")***.default***
} alt='error loading image'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I proffer two possible solutions:

1. Why don't you try importing the image at the top of the file then using the import name in the tag. e.g.

```
import MyImage from ../../../Assets/Home/footer-image.png;

<img src={MyImage} alt='error loading image'/>
```

2. Store your assets e.g. images, svg's within the public folder of the application then call the asset path directly within the image tag.

```
 <img src="%PUBLIC_URL%/footer-image.png" alt='error loading image'/>
```